# Automatic Acceptance of Transit Gateway Attachment from Another AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I have two AWS accounts and trying to do VPC sharing using a TransitGateway.

Account-A has the TGW and shared with Accunt-B using RAM. I execute a CloudFormation script in Account-B which creates a TransitGateway Attachment.

In Accunt-A I need to accept this TransitGateway Attachment and currently I am doing it manually.

I'm wondering if I can use CloudWatch or CloudTrail in Account-A to trigger a lambda function that accept the TransitGateway Attachment as and when it got created.

Comment: Are you trying to do vpc peering within two different aws accounts, If so you can write a cloudformation template following this url : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/peer-with-vpc-in-another-account.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can use AWS Organizations, then you can make the TG created in Account A magically appear in Account B, and Account A will automatically accept Account B's TG attachment.

In AWS Organizations, Account B will need to be in an Organizational Unit, with Account A being in the root.